# How to use the data generated in a specific class in another class? (in python)

Tags: python, oop

I'm new in python and in OO programming, so I don't know if the following question makes sense (...but I think it's a nice way to learn):

I'm trying to have two classes. One that generates data (call it `DataGen()`) and another that is able to process this data and give me some statistics (call it `Stats()`). I want to put both in different py files to keep it cleaner and so I can add methods to Stats.py without touching DataGen.py. Something like this:
In DataGen.py

```
class DataGen(object):  
    def __init__(self, number_of_samples, arg2):
        self.X = np.zeros([number_of_samples,1])
        # etc..
    def samples(self):
        # do some sampling and save it in self.X
```

In Stats.py

```
class Stats(object):  
    def __init__(self, something):
        # something here to initialize
        # etc..
    def mean(self):
        # calculate the mean using something like DataGen.X
```

Now, and here comes the part where I get lost. I want `Stats()` to work on the data belonging to an instance of `DataGen()`, but I don't know how to link the data contained in `DataGen.X` to `Stats`, so I can use the data every time I sample with `DataGen.samples()`.

I tried to construct an instance of `DG = DataGen(arg1,arg2)` and then pass this object to `S = Stats(DG)`. However, if I initialize this way, the data used to estimate the statistics didn't changed after I sampled again with `DataGen.samples()`. I guess every time I sample, I have to create an instance `S = Stats(DG)` with the new data. This seems bad... is there anyway I can attach this `Stats()` class to the data of `DataGen()`? Is this a bad idea/horrible construct?

I also don't know how I should think about this if I construct something where `DataGen` inherits the methods of Stats, or something similar. If `DataGen` inherits from `Stats`, but `Stats` needs the data from `DataGen`, how can I solve this loop? If `Stats` inherits from `DataGen`, do I need to create a single instance of Stats and then sample with it instead of `DataGen`, as `Stats.DataGen.samples()` or `Stats.samples()`. I wouldn't like that because the rest of my code uses `DataGen()` and I think it is better structured if I don't use `Stats()` to sample!

Does the above makes sense? Any comment regarding this would be very helpful!

Comment: I would check pandas library... (http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: if you pass Datagen object in constructor and then you run .samples() which change the dataget object internal values it should be seen by stats class but you need to rerun your stat. Can you show the code that you pass the datagen in stats constructor and example when it does not work as i think the issue is there . your OOP understanding looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone new to Python and OO you're getting the hang of encapsulation very well. You will want to follow the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) here which is where one object owns some info (DataGen) and some other object is interested in that info (Stats) and wants to be updated when it changes.

The way to do this is to pass a function from the interested object to owner object which can then be called when that info changes. The function is called either a callback or a listener.

```
class DataGen(object):  
    def __init__(self, number_of_samples, arg2):
        self.X = np.zeros([number_of_samples,1])
        self.listeners = list()

    def samples(self):
        # do some sampling and save it in self.X 
        # Call back to the listener and let it know that your samples changed.
        for listener in self.listeners:
            listener.samples_changed(self.X)

    def add_listener(self, listener):
        listeners.append(listener)

class Stats(object):
    def __init__(self, data_gen):
        # Register this 'observer' with the 'observable'
        something.add_listener(self)

    def samples_changed(self, samples):
        # Recalculate mean.

    def mean(self):
        # calculate the mean using something like DataGen.X
```

Here is an example of an object adding itself as a listener for another object.

1. Stats registers itself as a listener with `DataGen`
2. You call `samples()` on `DataGen`
3. `samples()` iterates through all of its listeners (there may be more than one stats) and calls `samples_changed(self.X)` on each one, passing the new set of samples.
4. One of those listeners (the only one in this case) is `Stats`, which can update its internal state to handle the new samples.

If at some time you want to remove the `Stats` object you must make sure you remove it from the `DataGen.listeners` list, otherwise you will end up with a memory leak.